# RxKotlin - Process gets terminated when dispose is called

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-kotlin

i am trying the upload the image through rxkotlin, my problem is when i close my screen in my application, the uploading process gets terminated because am adding that subscription to my disposal, so when my screen closes or destroys i will be disposing. because of this dispose my job getting terminated, since anyway i need to dispose else it my leads to the memory leak

```
fun uploadImage(imagePath : String){
   uploadToServer(imagePath)
        .subscribe()
        .addTo(disposal)   
}

override onCleared(){
   disposal.dispose()
}
```

So in this way i doing this, is there is any other way to continue this work, even after the screen destroys or cleared without memory leak ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ViewModel` are **independent of activity/fragment lifecycles or just their configuration changes class**, because of that `onCleared` is called only after the activity is finished. So don't dispose the Rx variables on `onCleared`. It is better to dispose them on `onDestroy`

```
override onDestory(){
super.onDestroy()
disposal.dispose()
}
```

Comment: even disposing on ondestroy of that activity i need to continue the work.

Comment: You should use a service for that